# How to modify a key (image or label ) on android's default keyboard

Tags: android, image, keyboard, ime

Its not about IME options. I want to modify the return key with a image(or different label)
for my edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per I know we can set **IME options**, **Input Type**, **IME action label** or **IME action id**  but we cant set any drawable image for default keyboard.. But if you want this then you can create your own custom keyboard..

just check this [link..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeActionId)